# How can I avoid to copy and paste this code (similar newcommand definitions using different functions) :

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I've been improving my code thanks to you guys, but this still looks improvable as it looks like an ugly copy/paste :

```
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheInf}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FInfAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheEga}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FEgaAUn(#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheSup}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FSupAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
```

The only differences between the 3 commands defined here are on which function will be called to compute the y-coordinate of the arrow extremity.

I've removed a lot for the MWE but it's still big :

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math} % Pour evaluate
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % Pour postionnement relatif

\def\FInfAUn(#1,#2){( 1 - ( (exp(-W*#1*#2)/sqrt(1-#1*#1)) *cos((W*#2*sqrt(1-#1*#1) 
                    - (atan(#1/sqrt(1-#1*#1))*pi/180) ) *180/pi) )  ) *\Kg }

\def\FTUn(#1){( 1/( W*(#1-sqrt((#1*#1) -1))) )}
\def\FTDeux(#1){( 1/(W *(#1+sqrt((#1*#1) -1))) )}
\def\FInterSupAUn(#1,#2,#3){(  \Kg * (1 - ( 1/( #1 - #2 ) )*( #1 *exp(-#3/ #1 ) - #2 *exp(-#3/ #2 ) ))   )}
\def\FSupAUn(#1,#2){ \FInterSupAUn({\FTUn(#1)},{\FTDeux(#1)},#2)   }
\def\FEgaAUn(#1){ \Kg * (1 - ( 1+ #1/(1/W) )*exp(-#1/(1/W)) )  }

    \newcommand*{\LegendFlecheInf}[5]{ 
        \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FInfAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }
    \newcommand*{\LegendFlecheEga}[5]{ 
        \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FEgaAUn(#2) }) ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }
    \newcommand*{\LegendFlecheSup}[5]{ 
        \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FSupAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }

\tikzset{ fleche/.style={<-,>=latex,line width=0.2mm,shorten <=-0.02cm} }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    W=pi*2;
  }]
\def\Kg{2}
\def\Ezero{1} 
\def\Ttrace{3}

\begin{axis}[ymax=1.55*\Kg]
    \addplot[blue,loosely dashed,thick=3pt,ultra thick,domain=0:3] {  \FEgaAUn(x)  };  \label{d}

    %\LegendFleche{z}{t}{Anchor of new node}{New node name}{previous node anchor coinsiding with this anchor}
    \LegendFlecheInf{0.2}{0.6}{west}{C3}{($(C2)+(axis cs:0.5,0.05)$)}
    \LegendFlecheSup{4}{0.6}{west}{C3}{($(C2)+(axis cs:1,-0.5)$)}
    \LegendFlecheSup{2}{0.6}{south}{C4}{(C3.north)}
    \LegendFlecheEga{1}{0.6}{south}{C5}{(C4.north)}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace

```
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheInf}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FInfAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheEga}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FEgaAUn(#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
\newcommand*{\LegendFlecheSup}[5]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { \FSupAUn(#1,#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
```

by

```
\newcommand*{\Legendx}[6]{ 
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, { #6(#1,#2) }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
```

and then replace for example

```
\LegendFlecheEga{1}{0.6}{south}{C5}{(C4.north)}
```

by

```
\Legendx{1}{0.6}{south}{C5}{(C4.north)}\FEgaAUn
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just need to change the FEgaAUn one to make it use 2 parameter like the others.

Answer (score 0):

With the `ifthen` package you can replace the three commands with a new command:

```
\newcommand{\LegendComplex}[6]{  
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{inf}}{\coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {\FInfAUn(#1,#2)});}{}
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{sup}}{\coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {\FSupAUn(#1,#2)});}{}
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{ega}}{\coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {\FEgaAUn(#2)});}{}      
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#1$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
```

You have to give a new parameter (sup, inf or ega) specifying which function you want to call.